# Adding dynamic records in parquet format

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet, pyarrow

I'm working on building a data lake and stuck on a very trivial thing. I'll be using Hadoop/HDFS as our data lake infrastructure and storing records in parquet format. The data will come from a Kafka queue which sends a json record every time. The keys in the json record could vary message to message. For example in the first message keys could be 'a', 'b' and in the second message keys could be 'c', 'd'.
I was using [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html) to store files in parquet format but as per my understanding we've to predefine schema. So when I try to write the second message, it'll throw an error saying that keys 'c' 'd' are not defined on schema.
Could someone guide as to how to proceed with this? Any other libraries apart from pyarrow also works but with this functionality.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of how you are doing this?

Comment: You'd have to define a Parquet schema with every possible key and then write into that, with the unused keys set to `null`.

Comment: Parquet requires a schema. I suggest you use Kafka with a Schema Registry to force your producers to send structured events

Answer (score 0):

Parquet supports Map types for instances where fields are unknown ahead of time. Or, if some of the fields are known, define more concrete types for those, possibly making them nullable, however you cannot mix named fields with a map on the same level of the record structure.

I've not used Pyarrow, but I'd suggest using Spark Structured Streaming and defining a schema there. Especially when consuming from Kafka. Spark's default output writer to HDFS uses Parquet.